# How do I put 2 or more values in a JSONArray that is inside a JSONObject in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I wanted to put an array of values inside a JSONObject and it should look like this when I save it into the database:

```
{
"specName":"Material",
"specValue":"Fabric",
"specName":"Height",
"specValue":
   [' 
     '{
       "m",  
       "cm", 
       "mm"
      },  
   '] 
}';
```

The thing is a user would specify an attribute, say for example **"Height"** and its allowed types/unit of measurement for example are *"meter, centimeter, and millimeter"*. My current code is below:

```
JSONArray itemTypeArray = new JSONArray();
itemTypeArray.put(specValue);

JSONObject itemTypeObj = new JSONObject();
itemTypeObj.put("specName", specName);
itemTypeObj.put("specValue", itemTypeArray);

itemType.setItemSpecs(itemTypeObj);
```

But when this saves on the database, it's not as I expected and I am having a hard time looking for answers and my last resort is to ask it here. The current value that saves to the database is as follows:

```
{"specName":"Material,Height","specValue":["Fabric, m, cm, mm"]}
```

It adds everything up on the same field.

My HTML code is this:

```
 <div>
    <label>Type: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{typeName}" />
 </div>
 <div>
     <div class="specFields-wrapper">

     </div>

     <button type="button" class="c-button submit" onclick="addSpec();">Add Specification</button>
</div>
<script text="text/javascript">
    function addSpec() {
        let specFieldLabel = '<span>Label: <input type="text" name="specName"></span>\r\n';
        let specFieldValue = '<span>Value: <input type="text" name="specValue"></span>\r\n';

        document.querySelector('.specFields-wrapper').innerHTML += (specFieldLabel+specFieldValue)+'<br>';
    }
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You specify a Duplicate key named specValue in a json node. When the map tries to put it the second time, it just updates the first entry. Some javadoc: If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced by the specified value.

Comment: Should your JSON look like: `[{"specName":"Material", "specValue":"Fabric"}, {"specName":"Height", "specValue":["m", "cm", "mm"]}]`?

Comment: @AlexRudenko yes that's how it's supposed to look

Comment: @Kostakiiiis I think it's because the html I wrote is only adding a new field which is exactly the same as the first one being added the first time the button gets clicked. I'm not exactly sure what to do...

Answer (score 1):

Check out this example

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      JSONObject json1 = new JSONObject();
      json1.put("specName", "Material");
      json1.put("specValue", "Fabric");

      JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject();
      json2.put("specName", "Height");
      json2.put("specValue", new JSONArray(Arrays.asList("m","cm","mm")));

      JSONArray array  = new JSONArray();
      array.put(json1.toMap());
      array.put(json2.toMap());

      String jsonFormatted = array.toString(2);
      System.out.println(jsonFormatted);
   }
```

Comment: I see this example results to what I needed for the output, but I think the issue really comes from how the HTML and JavaScript behaves, I still haven't figured it out. Thanks for this though.